# Can we decrypt (symmetric encryption/decryption) messages using OpenSSL in C without knowing the size of the plaintext?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

I am using the following code to encrypt and decrypt binary data with C in windows using openssl. As you can see, in both functions, I know the size of the plain text. Is there any way I can decrypt messages without knowing the size of the plain text?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
char * Encrypt(char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
    {
    static char*    Res;
    int             n = 0;
    DES_cblock      Key2;
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    Res = (char *)malloc(size);
    /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
    memcpy(Key2, Key, 8);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&Key2);
    DES_set_key_checked(&Key2, &schedule);
    /* Encryption occurs here */
    DES_cfb64_encrypt((unsigned char *)Msg, (unsigned char *)Res,size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_ENCRYPT);
    return (Res);
}
char * Decrypt(char *Key, char *Msg, int size)
{
    static char*    Res;
    int             n = 0;
    DES_cblock      Key2;
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    Res = (char *)malloc(size);
    /* Prepare the key for use with DES_cfb64_encrypt */
    memcpy(Key2, Key, 8);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&Key2);
        DES_set_key_checked(&Key2, &schedule);
    /* Decryption occurs here */
    DES_cfb64_encrypt((unsigned char *)Msg, (unsigned char *)Res,size, &schedule, &Key2, &n, DES_DECRYPT);
    return (Res);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char key[] = "password";
    char clear[] = "This is a secret message";
    char *decrypted;
    char *encrypted;
    encrypted = (char *)malloc(sizeof(clear));
    decrypted = (char *)malloc(sizeof(clear));
    printf("Clear text\t : %s : sizeof: %i\n", clear, strlen (clear));
    memcpy(encrypted, Encrypt(key, clear, sizeof(clear)), sizeof(clear));
    printf("Encrypted text\t : %s sizeof: %i\n", encrypted, strlen(encrypted));
    memcpy(decrypted, Decrypt(key, encrypted, sizeof(clear)), sizeof(clear));
    printf("Decrypted text\t : %s sizeof: %i\n", decrypted, strlen(decrypted));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why ask if you can easily try it?

Comment: I think mjan635 is asking to know how much memory to allocate.  The answer is that you typically encrypt and decrypt in "chunks" that are smaller than the total size.  In this case, every time you decrypted a chunk you'd append it to your buffer.  If you didn't have room, you'd `realloc` the buffer to make it larger.  You'd do that until you had no more data left to read.  You still have to know the length of the encrypted data stream somehow, or have a marker (like EOF if you read it from a file) that tells you how much data to read, though.

Answer (score 0):

With just cipher feedback? Sure thing, as long as you know where the block boundaries are you are golden (i.e. you need to know *where* you are in the ciphertext).